# Is this an ordered basis

Tags: change-of-basis

I was just having trouble with this question.

If $S=[e_1-e_2,e_3]$ where $e_1=(1,0,0), e_2=(0,1,0), e_3=(0,0,1)$

Would the list $S$ be an ordered basis of $\Bbb R^3$

Help would really be appreciated on this one guys

Comment: Yes, It's a basis written in a particular order.

Comment: Hey would it be possible to show me why it would just really help when I try other questions

Comment: All I did was read the words "basis" and "ordered" and see that they described what you wrote down. Reading the words (then in this case going back to the definitions) is always a good problem solving strategy.

Comment: As written $S$ has two elements:  $e_1-e_2$ and $e_3$.  is that what you intended?

Comment: OOPS I didn't read carefully. @lulu 's comment is crucial. My answer is right if the $-$ sign is a typo, Hurkyl 's is right if the $-$ is what you meant. So the moral is still "read carefully".

Comment: Yes I just meant for S=[e1-e2,e3]  I was just confused about it only having 2 elements and didn't know how to prove linear independence

Comment: The edit by @Dave changes the meaning, since $\{ e_1 - e_2, e_3 \}$ surely means a set, which is unordered. I've changed that back to square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

As

- $S$ has two elements
- $\mathbb{R}^3$ is three dimensional
- The number of elements in a basis for a vector space is the dimension of the space

$S$ can't possibly be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: How about for T=[2e1-e2 , e2+e3 , 2e1 +e3]   I got this to be an ordered basis of R^3 because the list of vectors it forms are linearly independent, am I right in thinking so?

Answer (score 0):

With given

$$S = \left\{ {{e_1} - {e_2},{e_3}} \right\}$$

we try to find a representation

$$u \cdot \left( {{e_1} - {e_2}} \right) + v \cdot {e_3} = \left( {{x_1},{x_2},{x_3}} \right)$$

for any $\left( {{x_1},{x_2},{x_3}} \right) \in {\mathbb{R}^3}$.

That is

$$u \cdot \left( {1, - 1,0} \right) + v \cdot \left( {0,0,1} \right) = \left( {{x_1},{x_2},{x_3}} \right)$$

or

$$\left( {u, - u,v} \right) = \left( {{x_1},{x_2},{x_3}} \right)$$

Comparing, we see

$$\begin{gathered}
  u = {x_1} \hfill \\
  u =  - {x_2} \hfill \\
  v = {x_3} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$

Which means

$${x_2} =  - {x_1}$$

So, only vectors with shape

$$\left( {{x_1}, - {x_1},{x_3}} \right) \in {\mathbb{R}^3}$$

can be represented by $S$.

And there are a lot more vectors of ${\mathbb{R}^3}$, which haven't
this kind of shape.

$S$ can't be an ordered base.